How to restore/unhide "Messages" and "Message rates" columns on the "Queues and Streams" tab in the RabbitMQ Management Console
I'm running the newest rabbitmq (3.13) container based on rabbitmq docker image. For some reason instead of "Queues" it has "Queues and Streams" tab in the management console (web UI). I think that is because "rabbitmq_stream" plugin (https://www.rabbitmq.com/docs/stream#enabling-plugin) is enabled.
Probably due to the plugin enabled the "queues" table doesn't contain "Messages" and "Message rates" columns (with the "unacked" subcolumn).
I tried to disable that plugin, but the container crashes every time (see the attached screen).
I expected that would restore the old "Queues" tab with the old table having the "unacked" column.
I'm not sure whether that is the correct way to archive the main goal - unhide those columns with the "unacked" sub-column.
https://i.sstatic.net/3SrosNlD.png - trying to disable the plugin
https://i.sstatic.net/TMrFZyJj.png - the container Web UI without the mentioned columns
https://i.sstatic.net/TX2LV3Jj.png - an example of UI with the columns
UPD. Sorry, the form validation doesn't allow saving images in the post.
UPD2. Here is the docker-compose configuration
version: '3.8'
services:
  rabbitmq:
    profiles:
      - aux
    user: rabbitmq
    image: rabbitmq:3.10
    healthcheck:
      test: rabbitmq-diagnostics -q ping
      interval: 3s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 3
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=${RABBITMQ_USER:-testuser}
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=${RABBITMQ_PASSWORD:-testpassword}
      - RABBITMQ_LOG='console=debug,+color,exchange=debug'
    ports:
      - '5672:5672'
      - '15672:15672'
    configs:
      - source: plugins
        target: /etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins
    networks:
      - internal-docker-network
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 384M
        reservations:
          cpus: '0.01'
          memory: 128M

networks:
  internal-docker-network:
    driver: bridge

configs:
  plugins:
    content: "[rabbitmq_management, rabbitmq_mqtt]."


Checked and found out a difference between a docker image with the issue (the one you reference in your docker file) and one without (rabbitmq:3.10-management).
Checking the dockerfile for the latter
It explains the "issue":

# make sure the metrics collector is re-enabled (disabled in the base image for Prometheus-style metrics by default)
rm -f > /etc/rabbitmq/conf.d/20-management_agent.disable_metrics_collector.conf;
\

So if you overwrite /etc/rabbitmq/conf.d/20-management_agent.disable_metrics_collector.conf in your compose
with value management_agent.disable_metrics_collector = false
the metrics you're looking for should show up again.
Alternatively, you could also switch to rabbitmq:3.10-management image
